# comparing 2 lists

Tags: apex, map, list

I modified my code to the below - works fine if the id is found, but when the id is not found, it sends an email that the id is found with status as null.

```
string s; 

boolean b;

for(Imp__c em: mp){ 

if(ex1.containsKey(em.actual__c)){

 b=true; 

s = em.Status__c; } 

else{ 

b=false; } 

} 

if(b=true){

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage successmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

successmail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

successmail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');

successmail.setSubject('Your Id is found:');

successmail.setPlainTextBody('Your Id is with status'+s);

mails.add(successmail);

Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

    }

     if(b=false){

          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage failmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

failmail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

failmail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');

failmail.setSubject('Your Id is not found:');

failmail.setPlainTextBody('Please check again');

mails.add(failmail);

Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

      }
```

Comment: `if(b=true){` is an assignment operation, not an equality comparison. This code will assign and immediately evaluate to `true`. Change your comparisons to use a double equals. `if(b == true){`

Comment: Kudos, now i understood that i should start referring to https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code, as is, should not compile. At minimum, Maps and Lists require a type parameterization (e.g. `Map<String, Case>`). However, assuming that's a copy-paste error, the real reason why this code doesn't work is: `ex1.containsKey('em.actual__c')` is incorrect. You shouldn't be using quotes here, because this means you're trying to look up a literal string key that most likely isn't in your map. Instead, you meant to look up by the field itself:

```
if(ex1.containsKey(em.actual__c)) {
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, now, it says, id is found every time (even when id doesn't exist), also whenever id is found it shows same picklist value for status as approved( i have 3 picklist values approved, rejected , in progress).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help once again, Kudos, now i understood that i should start referring to https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm.

Answer (score 5):

The one thing that jumps out is this line here:

```
if(ex1.containsKey('em.actual__c')){  //using a string
```

I believe you meant:

```
if(ex1.containsKey(em.actual__c)){  //using the field
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, now i understood that i should start referring to https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the condition to the below - 
works fine if the id is found, 
but when the id is not found, it sends an email that the id is found with status as null.

string s;
boolean b;

for(Imp__c em: mp){
          if(ex1.containsKey(em.actual__c)){
             b=true;
              s = em.Status__c;
          }
          else{
              b=false;
          }
      }
        if(b=true){

```
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage successmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
successmail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
successmail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');
          successmail.setSubject('Your Id is found:');
          successmail.setPlainTextBody('Your Id is with status'+s);
    mails.add(successmail);
          Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }

      if(b=false){
          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage failmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
failmail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
failmail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');
          failmail.setSubject('Your Id is not found:');
          failmail.setPlainTextBody('Please check again');
    mails.add(failmail);
          Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
      }
```

Thanks for your time.